# AS3 Loader() - loading multiple images with one loader

Tags: actionscript-3

I am attempting to load multiple images in AS3 and I'm exploring different options on how this can be done.

I would like to have to only use one Load() instance and handle the various image assignments in the onComplete handler...

here is my first attempt:

```
var buttonLdr:Loader = new Loader();
buttonLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoadError);
buttonLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);

whichButton = 0;
buttonLdr.load(new URLRequest("images/test.png"));

whichButton = 1;
buttonLdr.load(new URLRequest("images/testDown.png"));

whichButton = 2;
buttonLdr.load(new URLRequest("images/testHover.png"));

private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void
{
    switch(whichButton)
    {
        case 0:
            buttonBgUp = e.target.loader.content;
            break;
        case 1:
            buttonBgDown = e.target.loader.content;
            break;
        case 2:
            buttonBgHover = e.target.loader.content;
            break;
    }
    create();
}
```

A pretty straightforward approach... although it only calls the function on the last call, setting the buttonBgHover, but nothing else.

Any guidance to what might be going on here would be greatly appreciated.

-thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call next load only when previous load completes.

```
whichButton = 0;
buttonLdr.load(new URLRequest("images/test.png"));
private function onLoadComplete(e:Event):void
{
switch(whichButton)
{
    case 0:
         buttonBgUp = e.target.loader.content;
        whichButton = 1;
        buttonLdr.load(new URLRequest("images/testDown.png"));
        break;
    case 1:
         buttonBgDown = e.target.loader.content;
        whichButton = 2;
        buttonLdr.load(new URLRequest("images/testHover.png"));
        break;
    case 2:
        buttonBgHover = e.target.loader.content;             
        break;
}
create();
```

}

Comment: Well, that will get the job done, but that kind of cascading logic is far from ideal in terms of maintaining the code, or for serving as a basis for a load manager that can grow and gain functionality. Because this is a learning website, I would propose ditching "whichButton" in favor of pushing your file URLs into a queue (array) and using Array.shift() until the queue is empty. That way, you can support adding files while a load is in progress, adding more round-robin Loaders, etc.. solid design.